# Get StartAddress of win32 thread from another process

Tags: c#, c++, dll, process, pinvoke

### Background:

I've written a multi-threaded application in Win32, which I start from C# code using `Process` class from `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Now, in the C# code, I want to get the name/symbol of the start address of each thread created in the Win32 application so that I could log thread related information, such as CPU usage, to database. Basically, C# code starts multiple instances of the Win32 Application, monitors them, kills if needed, and then logs info/error/exceptions/reason/etc to database.

For this purpose, I've wrapped two Win32 API viz. [`SymInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681351(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SymFromAddr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx) in programmer-friendly API written by myself, as listed below:

```
extern "C"
{
    //wraps SymInitialize
    DllExport bool initialize_handler(HANDLE hModue);

    //wraps SymFromAddr
    DllExport bool get_function_symbol(HANDLE hModule, //in
                                       void *address,  //in
                                       char *name);    //out
}
```

And then call these API from C# code, using pinvoke. But it does not work and `GetLastError` gives `126` [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) which means:

> The specified module could not be found

I'm passing `Process.Handle` as `hModule` to both functions; `initialize_handler` seems to work, but `get_function_symbol` does not; it gives the above error. I'm not sure if I'm passing the correct handle. I tried passing the following handles:

```
Process.MainWindowHandle
Process.MainModule.BaseAddress
```

Both fail at the first step itself (i.e when calling `initialize_handler`). I'm passing `Process.Threads[i].StartAddress` as second argument, and that seems to be cause of the failure as `ProcessThread.StartAddress` seems to be the address of `RtlUserThreadStart` function, **not** the address of the start function specific to the application. The [MSDN says about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.startaddress.aspx):

> Every Windows thread actually begins execution in a system-supplied function, not the application-supplied function. The starting address for the primary thread is, therefore, the same (as it represents the address of the system-supplied function) for every Windows process in the system. **However, the StartAddress property allows you to get the starting function address that is specific to your application.**

But it doesn't say how to get the startinbg function address specific to the application, using ProcessThread.StartAddress.

### Question:

My problem boils to getting the start address of win32 thread from another application (written in C#), as once I get it, I will get the name as well, using the above mentioned APIs.  So how to get the start address?

---

I tested my symbol lookup API from C++ code. It works fine to resolve the address to a symbol, if given the correct address to start with.

Here is my p/invoke declarations:

```
[DllImport("UnmanagedSymbols.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool initialize_handler(IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("UnmanagedSymbols.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool get_function_symbol(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr address, StringBuilder name);
```

Comment: You forgot to post the [DllImport] declarations, surely the cause of the problem if it works from C++.

Comment: @HansPassant: I realized that, and therefore I posted that immediately.

Comment: The return type needs [MarshalAs], C++ bool == byte.  But that's not likely the cause.  ProcessThread.StartAddress is iffy since a thread actually starts at a Windows function (RtlUserThreadStart).  The docs promise some help but I have no idea how well that could work out-of-process.  Clearly this is not something you have tested in C++.

Comment: I tested it in C++, and it returns the decorated function name which I pass as StartAddress to CreateThread.

Comment: Yes, I don't doubt it.  What you haven't tested is whether the ProcessThread.StartAddress value you get is accurate.  The error code says it isn't.  Attach a debugger to the process and have a look yourself.

Comment: @HansPassant: You seem to be right. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processthread.startaddress.aspx) says *"Every Windows thread actually begins execution in a system-supplied function, not the application-supplied function. The starting address for the primary thread is, therefore, the same (as it represents the address of the system-supplied function) for every Windows process in the system. **However, the StartAddress property allows you to get the starting function address that is specific to your application.**"* [Contd]

Comment: [Contd] But it doesn't say how to get the starting function address specific to the application, using `ProcessThread.StartAddress`.

Comment: Right.  Accurately walking the stack of a thread in another process normally requires a debugger, a good set of .pdb files and lots of luck.  Frame pointer omission is a particularly nasty optimization.

Comment: which means Windows doesn't provide a nice and reliable way to get the application specific start function of a thread if I've threadId (and processId)?

Comment: So do you want to use "name/symbol of the start address" to identify threads? If so, couldn't you not just track threads you create or set thread names to whatever you want?

Comment: @7vies: And how to do that? I want to know the thread names from another process which is written in C#. How would I do it? I don't know of any API that set thread names, in release mode.

Comment: @Nawaz, if you are in control of the other processes ( ie, they are your code ) then just use ( pick your favorite IPC mechanism here ) to communicate process ID & name.  I would suggest boost [Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) map.

Comment: I am wondering why do you need to get the start address on the C# side, rather than on the C++ side? Couldn't you pass thread ID instead of the `ProcessThread.StartAddress`, run that thread ID through the C++-side APIs that you said were working fine, and see if you get a different result?

Comment: _"Both fail at the first step itself (i.e when calling initialize_handler). I'm passing Process.Threads[i].StartAddress as second argument, and that seems to be cause of the failure"_ - I'm confused; if it fails at the first call, how can anything you pass _after that_ be the cause of the failure?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `SymFromAddr` need StartAddress; how am I supposed to  make it work with thread id which no API takes thread id in the first place?

Comment: @Nawaz I guess I am confused about the way you made it work in C++ project: didn't you have to call [`OpenThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684335(v=vs.85).aspx) and pass it a thread ID at some point?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: No. I just used the same process to know the address of the function. Here is how I wrote my test project in C++:  I created a DLL which exports both these function `initialize_handler` and `get_function_symbol`; then I just create another project (.exe) which creates few threads using `CreateThread`, then I call my API from the DLL to get the function name of the threads.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: [Contd]. Also, if I were to use `OpenThread`, then how could I call `SymFromAddr` eventually which is wrapped in `get_function_symbol`? After all, it requires function address.

Comment: I think there is an API to go from a thread handle to the address of the start function. On the other hand, that's probably the same API that .NET is using.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Really? I don't know of such API. So tell me the name of the API.

Comment: It is `NtQueryInformationThread`. [Here](http://majii.wordpress.com/page/2/) is an example of calling it.

Comment: ① The question title says “Given [...] start address, how to get the function name” and yet most of the question is preoccupied with obtaining the start address. ② The sentence “I'm passing Process.Threads[i].StartAddress as second argument” is unclear: as second argument of what function exactly? ③ What are you passing as third argument to `SymInitialize`? — Please fix these issues with your question, then you will have a higher chance of getting a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Timwi: There is only one function which takes more than one argument,  so I don't know why you asked "*as second argument of what function exactly?*". Second, why does it matter what I passed to `SymInitialize` if you clearly understood that my problem is *"obtaining the start address"*.

Comment: Don't you have to inject your code into the process that you are starting?  I would inject your wrapper code into the external process and use an RPC mechanism to get the results from C#.

Comment: @GalacticJello: I didn't really understand your comment. Please elaborate on that.

Comment: @Nawaz: I am not going to waste time defending myself against your vacuous insinuation that your writing is crystal clear and everyone else is the one that doesn’t get it. But just to give you a hint, there is actually mention in your question of at least *four* functions, two WinAPI and two of your own. Besides that, the reference to the “second argument” is in a paragraph whose first sentence is clearly talking about the single-parameter function. If this doesn’t explain how your writing is confusing, then I don’t think I can help you. (After all, I don’t claim any writing skills of my own.)

Comment: @Timwi: Who claims that my writing is *"crystal clear"*. Stop making strawman. If something is not clear, then ask for clarification. No need to troll here. As for the four APIs, what are those? Two of the APIs are wrappers of the other two. If one knows the signature of win32 API, he can also know to which function I pass `StartAddress` as second argument. This thing is, yes, very much, *crystal clear*.

Comment: [I give up.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The key is to call the [`NtQueryInformationThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. This is not a completely "official" function (possibly undocumented in the past?), but the documentation suggests no alternative for getting the start address of a thread.

I've wrapped it up into a .NET-friendly call that takes a thread ID and returns the start address as `IntPtr`. This code has been tested in x86 and x64 mode, and in the latter it was tested on both a 32-bit and a 64-bit target process.

One thing I did not test was running this with low privileges; I would expect that this code requires the caller to have the `SeDebugPrivilege`.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintProcessThreads(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
        PrintProcessThreads(4156); // some other random process on my system
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void PrintProcessThreads(int processId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Process Id: {0:X4}", processId));
        var threads = Process.GetProcessById(processId).Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>();
        foreach (var pt in threads)
            Console.WriteLine("  Thread Id: {0:X4}, Start Address: {1:X16}",
                              pt.Id, (ulong) GetThreadStartAddress(pt.Id));
    }

    static IntPtr GetThreadStartAddress(int threadId)
    {
        var hThread = OpenThread(ThreadAccess.QueryInformation, false, threadId);
        if (hThread == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new Win32Exception();
        var buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(IntPtr.Size);
        try
        {
            var result = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread,
                             ThreadInfoClass.ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress,
                             buf, IntPtr.Size, IntPtr.Zero);
            if (result != 0)
                throw new Win32Exception(string.Format("NtQueryInformationThread failed; NTSTATUS = {0:X8}", result));
            return Marshal.ReadIntPtr(buf);
        }
        finally
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
        }
    }

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int NtQueryInformationThread(
        IntPtr threadHandle,
        ThreadInfoClass threadInformationClass,
        IntPtr threadInformation,
        int threadInformationLength,
        IntPtr returnLengthPtr);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

    [Flags]
    public enum ThreadAccess : int
    {
        Terminate = 0x0001,
        SuspendResume = 0x0002,
        GetContext = 0x0008,
        SetContext = 0x0010,
        SetInformation = 0x0020,
        QueryInformation = 0x0040,
        SetThreadToken = 0x0080,
        Impersonate = 0x0100,
        DirectImpersonation = 0x0200
    }

    public enum ThreadInfoClass : int
    {
        ThreadQuerySetWin32StartAddress = 9
    }
}
```

Output on my system:

```
Process Id: 2168    (this is a 64-bit process)
  Thread Id: 1C80, Start Address: 0000000001090000
  Thread Id: 210C, Start Address: 000007FEEE8806D4
  Thread Id: 24BC, Start Address: 000007FEEE80A74C
  Thread Id: 12F4, Start Address: 0000000076D2AEC0
Process Id: 103C    (this is a 32-bit process)
  Thread Id: 2510, Start Address: 0000000000FEA253
  Thread Id: 0A0C, Start Address: 0000000076F341F3
  Thread Id: 2438, Start Address: 0000000076F36679
  Thread Id: 2514, Start Address: 0000000000F96CFD
  Thread Id: 2694, Start Address: 00000000025CCCE6
```

apart from the stuff in parentheses since that requires extra P/Invoke's.

---

Regarding `SymFromAddress` "module not found" error, I just wanted to mention that one needs to call `SymInitialize` with `fInvadeProcess = true` OR load the module manually, [as documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I know you say this isn't the case in your situation, but I'll leave this in for the benefit of anyone who finds this question via *those* keywords.

Comment: I tried this approach, and it worked; however the current form of this answer isn't compiling, and lacks lots of other info. So I will edit this answer sometime, adding more details including code, making it more perfect. Then I will accept this as answer (if I don't get more better answer). Thanks. :-)

Comment: Oh by the way, +1. Please delete the other answer. That didn't help me in any way.

Comment: Now this looks better, and sort of complete answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what my understanding of the problem is.

You have a C# app, APP1 that creates a bunch of threads.

Those threads, in turn, each create a process.  I am assuming those threads stay alive and are in charge of monitoring the process it spawned.

So for each thread in APP1, you want it to enumerate information on the threads spawned in the child process of that thread.

They way I would have done this back in the good-old-days would be:

- Code all my Win32 thread monitoring of a given Win32 process into a DLL
- Inject that DLL into the process I wanted to monitor
- Use a named pipe or other RPC mechanism to communicate from the injected Win32 process to the host APP1

So in your main threadproc in C#, you would create and monitor a named pipe for your process to communicate once it has been injected.

In C++ land, the pseudo code would be to then create a suspended process, allocate some memory in that process, inject your DLL into the process, then create a remote thread that would execute your injected dll:

```
char * dllName = "your cool dll with thread monitoring stuff.dll"

// Create a suspended process
CreateProces("your Win32 process.exe", ...CREATE_SUSPENDED..., pi)

// Allocate memory in the process to hold your DLL name to load
lpAlloc = VirtualAlloc(ph.hProcess, ... MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE)

// Write the name of your dll to load in the process memory
WriteProcessMemeory(pi.hProcess, lpAlloc, dllName, ...)

// Get the address of LoadLibrary
fnLoadLibrary = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA")

// Create a remote thread in the process, giving it the threadproc for LoadLibrary
// and the argument of your DLL name
hTrhead = CreateRemoteThread(pi.hProcess, ..., fnLoadLibrary, lpAlloc, ...)

// Wait for your dll to load
WaitForSingleObject(hThread)

// Go ahead and start the Win32 process
ResumeThread(ph.hThread)
```

In your DLL, you could put code into DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH that would connect to the named pipe you set up, and initialize all your stuff.  Then fire a function to begin monitoring and reporting on the named pipe.

Your C# threadproc would monitor the named pipe for its process, and report it on up to APP1.

**UPDATE:**

I missed the fact that you control the code for the Win32 proccess.  In that case, I would just pass an argument to the proccess that would control the RPC mechanism of your choice for communication (Shared memory, named pipes, queue service, clipboard (ha), etc).

That way, your C# threadproc sets up the RPC communication channel and monitoring, and then provides the "address" information to your Win32 process so it can "dial you back".

I'll leave the other stuff up there in case it is useful to anyone else wanting to monitor a Win32 process where they are not in charge of the code.

Comment: Forgot to mention my main point (or belief, someone correct me if I am wrong): you can't directly call a function in another process.

Comment: This idea sounds interesting. I must try this in my spare time, then I will come back to you. +1 for expounding on the approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is definitely not the straightforward approach, but maybe it will help you somehow. You should be able to get the stack trace of another thread in a way used by [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) project (StackWalk64) and eventually see the name of desired function. It has its own problems, particularly performance of this approach probably won't be too high, but as I understood this is one-shot per thread operation. Question is, will it generally be able to properly walk the stack of your (probably optimized) applications.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't really do this reliably: if you happen to access `Thread.StartAddress` before the thread executes the function pointer or after the function returns, you will have no way to know what the starting function actually is.

Secondly, the more likely answer is that there isn't a direct mapping to the starting function when the thread starting function is managed.