# How to get the name of a Win32 Thread?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, unmanaged

I know of the non-intuitive process to set the name of a thread under Windows (see "[How to set name to a Win32 Thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905876/how-to-set-name-to-a-win32-thread)").  Is there a way to get the name of the thread?  I don't see any Windows API that lets me do this ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: You can get the thread's start function name if that helps you in any way.

Comment: @Nawaz How would you do that?

Comment: @CS.: You've to use these API : [SymInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I've used them, see this topic : [Get StartAddress of win32 thread from another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8679406/get-startaddress-of-win32-thread-from-another-process)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Beginning with Windows 10, version 1607, you can now get the name of a thread using `GetThreadDescription()`, assuming `SetThreadDescription()` was used to set the name of the thread.

Here's an example:

```
HRESULT hr = GetThreadDescription(ThreadHandle, &data);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{   
    wprintf(“%ls\m”, data);
    LocalFree(data);
}
```

Here's the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt774972(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 18):

Threads don't actually have names in Win32. The process via `RaiseException` is just a "Secret Handshake" with the VS Debugger, who actually stores the TID => Name mapping. Windows itself has no notion of a thread "Name".

Answer (score 12):

There is no such WinAPI call since there exists no such thing as thread names.

If you set a thread name then the debugger of your IDE will store it for you, which makes it easier to debug.
However the name is never really attached to the thread by a windows API call.

If you run your application without a debugger then setting a thread name has no effect, therefore you can't retrieve the name.

Even if it would be accessible - I wouldn't write code that works only with a debugger attached. Better store the name for yourself together with the handle.

Comment: are you saying that there's absolutely no way to get the thread name that you've set in the debugger ?
I'd like to put some debug check in my code to make sure it's called from the right thread, using the thread name

Comment: The thread 0x66c has exited with code 0 (0x0) -> I thought, maybe the 0x66c is something like a name ?